# batch: filenames with variables evaluated inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file, filenames, evaluate

File names and directories containing variables are being evaluated indside procedures.  How do I make batch store the file's name as a variable without evaluating it?

EG: my path is:

```
"C:\Rare\Names in a File\%CD%\"
                              batchfile.bat
                              file.txt
```

I want to run a script inside this directory:

```
REM #####BATCHFILE.BAT#######

pushd "%dp0"
for %%A in ("C:\Test") do set EXEPATH=%%~A
for %%A in ("Test.exe") do set EXECUTABLE=%%~A
for %%A in ("%CD%") do set DIRNAME=%%~A
for %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "*.txt"') do (
SET FILENAME=%%~A
CALL :PROCEDURE
)
exit /b
:PROCEDURE
start /w "" "%EXEPATH%\%EXECUTABLE%" "%DIRNAME%\%FILENAME%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a menu in batch which is a little bit different to your problem.

You need to have one variable per file. The easiest way is to just increment their names:

```
var1=path1\exe1
var2=path1\exe2
var3=path2\exe1
var4=path2\exe2
```

On each variable in the for loop you could call a procedure which saves the file with the path in a variable.

```
for ....(
   call :Var %path% %file%
)

:Var
set /a id+=1
set %id%.path=%1&& shift
set %id%.file=%1
goto:EOF

after this you could do

for ..(1,1,%id%) do (
   start !%id%.path!\!%id%.file!
)
```

if you want to have a look at my Batch menu, you can contact me.